# Convert empty string to null using javax.validation annotations

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I have the following variable annotated for data validation:

```
@Size(min=8, max=16, message="the size of the parameter must be between 8 and 16")
private String param;
```

However, the `param` **can be null**.  It is required that it be 8-16 chars long only if it is not null.  The problem I face is if the client app (JSON API) supplies an empty string, I want to treat it as though it were not supplied at all, i.e. is null.  I was wondering if there is an elegant way to do this using the [`javax.validation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/package-summary.html) `annotations`, i.e. convert an empty string to null, as opposed to the plain Java way the way I'm doing it right now:

```
public void setParameter(String _param) {
    if(_param != null && !_param.trim().isEmpty()){
        this.param = _param;
    } else {
        this.param = null;
    }
}
```

I would like to have a very simple setter:

```
public void setParameter(String _param) {
    this.param = _param;
}
```

and have the is-empty-string boilerplate done by an annotation.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could can implement your own custom constraint validator.

see here. I've used this many times and works like a charm.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html

You would just need to set this condition (if null return "" or vice-versa) in the isValid method.